# Remove an element in a container using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I only want to scrape the required information contained in the black box, and delete/remove/exclude the information contained in the red box[image]

I am doing this because class names "entry" and "partial entry" exist in both boxes. Only the first "partial entry" contains the information that I need, so I plan to delete/remove/exclude the classname "mgrRspnInLine".

My code is:

```
while True:
    container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"review-container")]')
    for item in container:
        try:
            element = item.find_element_by_class_name('mgrRspnInline')
            driver.execute_script("""var element = document.getElementsByClassName("mgrRspnInline")[0];element.parentNode.removeChild(element);""", element)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"taLnk ulBlueLinks")]')))
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"taLnk ulBlueLinks")]')))
            element.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            rating = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"ui_bubble_rating bubble_")]')
            for rate in rating:
                rate = rate.get_attribute("class")
                rate = str(rate)
                rate = rate[-2:]
                score_list.append(rate)
            time.sleep(2)
            stay = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"recommend-titleInline noRatings")]')
            for stayed in stay:
                stayed = stayed.text
                stayed = stayed.split(', ')
                stayed.append(stayed[0])
                travel_type.append(stayed[1])
            WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"noQuotes")]')))
            summary = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"noQuotes")]')
            for comment in summary:
                comment = comment.text
                comments.append(comment)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"ratingDate")]')))
            rating_date = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"ratingDate")]')
            for date in rating_date:
                date = date.get_attribute("title")
                date = str(date)
                review_date.append(date)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"partial_entry")]')))
            review = item.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"partial_entry")]')
            for comment in review:
                comment = comment.text
                print(comment)
                reviews.append(comment)
        except (NoSuchElementException) as e:
            continue
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"nav next taLnk ui_button primary")]')))
        element.click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except (ElementClickInterceptedException,NoSuchElementException) as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

Basically within the "review-container" I searched first for the class name "mgrRspnInLine", then tried to delete it using the execute_script.

but unfortunately, the output still shows the contents contained in the"mgrRspnInLine".

Comment: Your code for removing element should work. There might be several elements with class name `mgrRspnInLine` (hidden?), so probably you're removing the wrong element... You can simplify your code to `driver.execute_script("""arguments[0].parentNode.removeChild(arguments[0]);""", element)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid matching second element by your XPath you can just modify XPath as below:

```
.//*[contains(@class,"partial_entry") and not(ancestor::*[@class="mgrRspnInLine"])]
```

This will match element with class name `"partial_entry"` only if it doesn't have ancestor with class name `"mgrRspnInLine"`

Comment: Awesome expression @sir Andersson. Always something new to learn.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first occurrence you could use css class selector instead of:

```
.partial_entry
```

and retrieve with `find_element_by_css_selector`:

```
find_element_by_css_selector(".partial_entry")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all the `.mgrRspnInLine` elements with:

```
driver.execute_script("[...document.querySelectorAll('.mgrRspnInLine')].map(el => el.parentNode.removeChild(el))")
```

Answer (score 0):

Stitching the comment by Andersson, and the two answers provided by QHarr, and pguardiario. I finally solved the problem.

The key is to target a container within the container, all the information is contained in the class name "ui_column is-9" which is contained in the class name "review-container", hence addressing Andersson's comment of multiple `mgrRspnInLine`.

Within the nested loop, I used pguardianrio's suggestion to delete existing multiple `mgrRspnInLine`, then adding QHarr's answer on .partial_entry

```
while True:
    container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"review-container")]')
    for items in container:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"taLnk ulBlueLinks")]')))
        element.click()
        time.sleep(10)
        contained = items.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"ui_column is-9")]')
        for item in contained:
            try:
                driver.execute_script("[...document.querySelectorAll('.mgrRspnInLine')].map(el => el.parentNode.removeChild(el))")
                rating = item.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class,"ui_bubble_rating bubble_")]')
                rate = rating .get_attribute("class")
                rate = str(rate)
                rate = rate[-2:]
                score_list.append(rate)
                time.sleep(2)
                stay = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"recommend-titleInline")]')
                stayed = stay.text
                stayed = stayed.split(', ')
                stayed.append(stayed[0])
                travel_type.append(stayed[1])
                WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"noQuotes")]')))
                summary = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"noQuotes")]')
                comment = summary.text
                comments.append(comment)
                WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"ratingDate")]')))
                rating_date = item.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[contains(@class,"ratingDate")]')
                date = rating_date.get_attribute("title")
                date = str(date)
                review_date.append(date)
                WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"partial_entry")]')))
                review = item.find_element_by_css_selector(".partial_entry")
                comment = review.text
                print(comment)
            except (NoSuchElementException) as e:
                continue
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'.//*[contains(@class,"nav next taLnk ui_button primary")]')))
        element.click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except (ElementClickInterceptedException,NoSuchElementException) as e:
        print(e)
        break
```